# How to concatenate row values for use in WHERE clause of T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I want to write a query in T-SQL to perform a search on two concatenated columns. The two columns are fname and lname. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    fname,
    lname,
    ...
FROM
    users
JOIN
    othertable ON foo=bar
WHERE
    fname+' '+lname LIKE '%query%'
```

SQL server doesn't like that syntax, though. How do I structure the query so that I can perform a WHERE LIKE operation that searches through two concatenated columns, allowing me to search the user's full name, rather than just first name and last name individually?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with that. Any error?

Comment: I performed a similar query on a Contacts table I have on sql server 2005, and the concatenation does not cause a problem, even with NULL values in one or both of the columns.

Comment: @Adrift: then you have a *deprecated* setting CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL set or compat mode of DB is set to 65 See MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: I got it working - I think one of the join conditions might have been causing a problem. When I rewrote it, the error was gone

Comment: @gbn: for my db, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is off and compat mode is 90.  The documentation you linked says that setting only determines whether a concatenation with a NULL value treats the NULL as NULL or as an empty string.  I don't think that would cause a syntax problem either way.

Comment: @gbn: and also +1 to your comment;  I was not aware of that setting and hopefully I'll remember it if I run into any unexpected behavior when concatenating strings in the db.

Comment: @Adrift: To clarify, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF makes NULL act like empty string. The default should be ON. And will be in future.

Answer (score 5):

I can only suggest that one of fname or lname is NULL so the LIKE fails., (NULL concat anything is null)

Try

```
...
ISNULL(fname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(lname, '') LIKE '%query%'
```

However, I would use a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(SQL.90).aspx) and consider indexing it because this will run awfully.

Comment: Can you point me to any good resources on how to add a computed column?

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to add a calculated column to your table for full_name
calculated column examples:

```
--drop table #test
create table #test (test varchar (10) , test2 varchar (5),[Calc]  AS right(test, 3))
Insert #test
values('hello', 'Bye')
Insert #test
values('hello-bye', null)


Alter table #test
add [MyComputedColumn]  AS substring(test,charindex('-',test), len(test)),
Concatenatedcolum as test+ ' ' +test2
select * from #test
```

As you can see you may have to play around a bit until you get the results you want. Do that in a temp table first to avoid having to restructure the database table multiple times. For names, especially if you are using middle name which is often blank, you may need to add some code to handle nulls. You may also need to have code sometimes to cast to the same datatype if one filed you are concatenating is an int for instance and the other  a varchar.

Comment: Can you point me to a good resource on how to add a calculated column

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the join conditions might be causing a problem. Try rewriting it, you may find the error goes away ;)